# How to read XML generated from JAXB with C

Tags: java, c, xml, jaxb, libxml2

I created Java object and I used JAXB to convert that object into XML. Now the problem is how I can read this XML file in C? Is there any standard way or I have to use external libraries like `libxml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libxml2 is the "standard" way (inasmuch as there is a standard) to handle XML in C/C++.  At least it has the most mindshare and best documentation and community support, AFAICT.

Unless, of course, you want to write your own XML parser, which is not recommended :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xerces-C APIs to read the XML. Xerces apis exists for both C/C++ and Java. Refer the project website http://xerces.apache.org/